# How to do recurring with bank account payment mode using authorized.net

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, payment-processing, activemerchant, recurring-billing

I am using recurring facility of authorized.net using active_merchant plugin in rails.
there are two payment method for this

```
1] Credit Card
2] Bank Account
```

**I successfully done it using Credit Card**

For Recurring i need my Test Mode off.
Also my E-check, credit card processing, and subscriptions are all enabled.

But i am not able to subscribed using Bank Account

Following is my code

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :developer

#i found follwing test bank account on net
    account  = ActiveMerchant::Billing::Check.new(:account_holder_type=>"personal",:account_number=>"123123123", :account_type => "savings", :name=>"name", :routing_number=>"244183602")

    if account.valid? #this comes true
      gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(:login => 'Mylogin', :password => 'Mypassword')
      response = gateway.recurring( amount, nil, {:interval =>{:length=>@length, :unit =>:months},
                                        :duration =>{:start_date=>'2010-04-24', :occurrences=>1},
                                        :billing_address=>{:first_name=>'dinesh', :last_name=>'singh'},
                                        :bank_account=>{:account_holder_type=>"personal",:account_number=>"123123123", :account_type => "savings", :name_of_account=>"name", :routing_number=>"244183602"}
                                       })

if response.success?  #this comes false

  else
    puts response.message   ####>> ERROR
    render :action=>"account_payment"
  end
```

I get Follwing **ERROR** when i debug for response.message

```
"The test transaction was not successful. (128) This transaction cannot be processed."
```

Am i doing anything wrong i search for the another Test Bank Account Data but i didn't find it.